# webpack code split handlebars file -- results in large file

Tags: javascript, webpack

My demo app has two buttons that need to load a new handlebars template on click.

```
    var $ = require('jquery');

    $(function(){
        $('.js_hbs-1').on('click', function(){
            var $button = $(this);
            var initText = $button.text();
            $button.text('Loading...');

            require.ensure([], function(){
                var template = require('handlebars!./test.hbs');
                var html1 = template({'number': 10000});

                $button.text(initText);
                $('.append-here').html(html1);
            });
        });

        $('.js_hbs-2').on('click', function(){
            var $button = $(this);
            var initText = $button.text();
            $button.text('Loading...');

            require.ensure([], function(){
                var template = require('handlebars!./test2.hbs');
                var html2 = template({'number': 20000})
                $('.append-here').html(html2);
                $button.text(initText);
            });
        });
    });
```

---

### Demo here: http://www.webpackbin.com/4krNSrrG-

All this is fine except that the compiled file has ~250kb for a 1 line hbs file.

I am really new to webpack, I know that there are some plugins you can configure, but none seem to work.

My webpack config file

```
    var webpack = require("webpack");

    module.exports = {
        context: __dirname + "/public/javascripts/",
        entry: {
            app: "./app",
        },
        output: {
            path: __dirname + "/public/javascripts/dist",
            filename: '[name].bundle.js',
            chunkFilename: "[id].bundle.js",
            publicPath: "../javascripts/dist/"
        },
        module: {
            loaders: [
                { test: /\.hbs/, loader: "handlebars-template-loader" }
            ]
        },
        devtool: "#inline-source-map"
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think webpack does some crazy things, but adding handlebars along a `vendor` entry solved my problem.

Resulting config:

```
    var webpack = require("webpack");

    module.exports = {
        entry: {
            app: __dirname + "/public/javascripts/app",
            vendor: [
                'backbone',
                'handlebars'
            ],
        },
        output: {
            path: __dirname + "/public/javascripts/dist",
            filename: '[name].bundle.js',
            chunkFilename: "[id].bundle.js",
            publicPath: "../javascripts/dist/"
        },
        module: {
            loaders: [
                { test: /\.hbs/, loader: "handlebars-template-loader" }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                name: 'vendor',
                minChunks: Infinity
            }),
        ],
        node: {
            fs: "empty"
        },
        devtool: "#inline-source-map"
    };
```

---

### Update

Looks like the previous code was working but the file size was 1MB bigger that after adding this solution: https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/953#issuecomment-94931306

This also solved these warnings: 
        WARNING in ./~/handlebars/lib/index.js
        require.extensions is not supported by webpack. Use a loader instead.

```
    WARNING in ./~/handlebars/lib/index.js
    require.extensions is not supported by webpack. Use a loader instead.

    WARNING in ./~/handlebars/lib/index.js
    require.extensions is not supported by webpack. Use a loader instead.
```

---

```
    var webpack = require("webpack");
    var path = require('path');

    module.exports = {
        entry: {
            app: __dirname + "/public/javascripts/app",
            vendor: [
                'backbone',
                'handlebars'
            ],
        },
        output: {
            path: __dirname + "/public/javascripts/dist",
            filename: '[name].bundle.js',
            chunkFilename: "[id].bundle.js",
            publicPath: "../javascripts/dist/"
        },
        module: {
            loaders: [
                { test: /\.hbs/, loader: "handlebars-template-loader" }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                name: 'vendor',
                minChunks: Infinity
            }),
        ],
        node: {
            fs: "empty"
        },
        devtool: "#inline-source-map",
        resolve: {
            modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
            fallback: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
            alias: {
                'handlebars': 'handlebars/runtime.js'
            }
        },
        resolveLoader: {
            fallback: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
            alias: {
                'hbs': 'handlebars-loader'
            }
        }
    };
```